# How can I disable the auto-generated Docs page under each Story in Storybook 7?

Tags: storybook

I migrated to Storybook 7 and now under each Story appeared Docs page.

I'm using custom mdx and I don't use addon-docs.

To get rid of autogenerated docs previously I could use the following config option:

```
docs: {
        autodocs: false,
    }
```

But now it doesn't help.

How to disable autodocs in Storybook 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable autodocs completely for your entire Storybook instance, you can add the following configuration to your `main.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  // other configuration...
  features: {
    // disable autodocs
    storyStoreV7: false,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable autodocs for a specific component, you can try this in your Meta block

```
export default {
  title: 'Example/Button',
  component: Button,
  **tags: ['autodocs']**,//Remove this line
  argTypes: {
    backgroundColor: { control: 'color' },
  },
};
```